# Gunner artillery fire

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing on "normal" difficulty and am about level 30.  When I am in combat with Gunner faction, I frequently get hit with artillery - I can hear the missile incoming and then the world turns to flame.

Are Gunners supposed to have artillery support?  If so, how can I keep from being insta-killed by it?

Comment: Does the "missile" sound like it's whistling? If so, that's actually a Fat Man.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it.  I've never fired the fat man so I didn't realize it had the same whistle sound.  I suppose "run" is the most effective defense against fat man?

Comment: @Gus Yes, running is the way to go. Running behind cover would be best. Maybe pop a Med-X real quick.

Comment: Whenever you hear the whistling sound, the solution is not to run.  The blast radius is massive and you can't possibly run far enough once you can hear it.  The first thing is to open your inventory, use a MedX and RadX right away.  Then you try to take the nearest cover to prevent a headshot.  There's just no time to even figure out where it came from.

Comment: Note that random spawns do not ever spawn with a fatman.  The ones that have fatman are near specific Gunner controlled areas.  The soldier with the fatman are always high up somewhere.

Comment: Can you outrun a fatman using any of the slow time drugs?  Like when you hear the whistle you use any of the Jet variants and run like a headless goose in one direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You (the player) are the only character capable of calling in an artillery strike (by using an [Artillery smoke grenade](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Artillery_smoke_grenade)).

I believe you are mistaking their use of a [Fat Man](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fat_Man_(Fallout_4)) (indicated by a shrill whistle that increases in volume as it approaches you).

From the wikia linked above:

> When fired from a long enough distance, the projectile makes a loud whistling noise which indicates one should get to cover ASAP.

Comment: The mini nuke that is launched from the Fat Man _definitely_ leaves the world around it in flames as well.  The gunners are also one of the few enemies that use the Fat Man from my experiences.

Comment: Your artillery fire creates the same explosion as the fatman.  The only way to get even more destruction is to use the mirv variant of the fatman.